# How to use nodejs generated JWT token to authenticate to a nginx file folder

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, jwt

I'm developing an application for a costumer and I'm using the nginx reverse proxy feature to call routes on my express application, since it's a mobile application I'm using JWT (jsonwebtoken) to authenticate the users, the app has a section that has features that send avatar images and get them after, but I want to protect this images request too! Is there a way to generate the token in the application (i already do this) and pass it to the user and then make the request with the token to nginx to access the images?? Does the secret has to be the same? How does it work?

Comment: The answer depends on where the images are being served from. Are you using express.static or serving outside of the node application from nginx?

Comment: I'm serving it with nginx

Comment: I would try [nginx-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt) if you can deal with the installation instructions (or use OpenResty). The secret will have to be the same if you are using symmetric key cryptography; if you are using something like RSA then nginx only needs the public key to verify the signature

Comment: I saw the documentation of nginx-jwt and actually it seems that it only supports hs256 so I'll try to use it sharing my secret from nodejs, let's start the configuration, thanks @grrizzly :D